# How determine if MSXML6 is installed in a system using Delphi?

Tags: xml, delphi, msxml

I have an application which depends of the [MSXML6](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=3988#overview), in most of the machines when the application is deployed this package is already installed, but in a few cases the MSXML6 is not installed, The question is how I can check if the MSXML 6 is already installed?

Comment: I believe the most reliable way is to simply *try* to create the ole object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can check if the CLSID exist in the registry using the [CLSIDFromProgID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms688386%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, for MSXML the CLSID is `Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0`

Check this sample app

```
uses
  ActiveX,
  SysUtils;

{
        Msxml2.DOMDocument.2.6
        Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0
        Msxml2.DOMDocument.4.0
        Msxml2.DOMDocument.5.0
        Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0
}
var
  clsid: TCLSID;
begin
  try
    if Succeeded(CLSIDFromProgID('Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0', clsid)) then
     Writeln('MSXML 6.0 Installed')
    else
     Writeln('MSXML 6.0 Not Installed');
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

Comment: That will only tell you if the CLSID exists in the Registry, not whether MSXML itself is actually functioning correctly.  To do that, you have to instantiate it via `CoCreateInstance()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, Indeed the OP can add the a call to the `CoCreateInstance` function too.